# Awk counting subfields

Tags: awk

I have a file with records that look like this:

```
11924  nt4dalmtg.er.usgs.gov            144.47.95.64               Sat, June/23/2001 7:21:57
```

I am trying to get a count for the number of sub fields that do not contain any numbers by using awk.

This is what I tried:

```
                 'BEGIN{FS=".+|/+| ";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~/[^0-9]/) j++}
                   END{ print  j}' file.txt
```

It returns nothing.   I tried some variations with the BEGIN END blocks but I am not sure if it is my code blocks or did I set field separators wrong?

Comment: You want to loop over the fields outside of `BEGIN` so you do it for your actual lines of data not just once at the beginning *before* you've read any data.

Comment: What do you call subfields? Is `nt4dalmtg` a subfield or is `nt4dalmtg.er.usgs.gov` a subfield?

Comment: any punctuation or existing spaces are sub fields, I omitted the ":" since they are strictly numeric

Answer (score 1):

you can try,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\.+|\\/+|[ ]+";} 
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^[^0-9]+$/) j++}
END{print j}' file
```

you get

```
5
```

the subfields are "er", "usgs", "gov", "Sat," and "June"

Answer (score 0):

just try to put the for loop in the processing block instead of BEGIN block...as below

```
# notice extra closed and open braces before for
$awk 'BEGIN{FS=".+|/+| ";} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~/[^0-9]/) j++}  END{print j}' file.txt
```